# How can I insert 2 columns without having null values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert 2 columns from different sources into Temp table, But every time I have `NULL` values I don't want these `NULL` values

I want to shift the pattern values to match the `patternID`

```sql
-- Create Temp table to hold the pattern ID and Pattern Value
CREATE TABLE #PatternTable(
    PatternID int, 
    PatternValue int,
)
-- Extract numbers from the pattern

INSERT INTO #PatternTable  (PatternID) 
SELECT * FROM  STRING_SPLIT( REPLACE('P1|P2|P3', 'P' , ''), '|') 

INSERT INTO #PatternTable  (PatternValue) 
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('863|881|226','|') 



SELECT * FROM #PatternTable pt
```

Comment: If you don't want the `NULL` values, have you considered using a `WHERE`?

Comment: The point is The values of the second column is shifted down by the values of the first one.

Comment: What does "shift the pattern values to match" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanted. The issue with `STRING_SPLIT()` is that it does not return a `sequence` value that can use the identify the ordering / sequencing of the delimited value. The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` is a workaround, thought not perfect and no guarantee of the ordering. If the ordering is important, search for string splitter function. There are lots of such function around

```
INSERT INTO #PatternTable (PatternID, PatternValue)
SELECT PatternID, PatternValue
FROM
(
    SELECT  value as PatternID, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM    STRING_SPLIT( REPLACE('P1|P2|P3', 'P' , ''), '|') 
) i
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  value as PatternValue, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM    STRING_SPLIT('863|881|226','|') 
) v on i.RN     = v.RN
```

If this is not what you wanted, please show your expected result

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
select pi.pattern_id, pv.pattern_value from
(select row_number() over (order by pattern_id) as rn, pattern_id from #PatternTable pt) pi
full join
(select row_number() over (order by pattern_value) as rn, pattern_value from #PatternTable pt) pv
on pi.rn = pv.rn
```

Comment: It worked but left me with last 3 columns null, Is there anyway I can insert 2 columns in the same time ?